# Fill a calendar with appointments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, calendar

In .NET MVC (C#) I need to create a calendar and fill it with events that come from a database. Most events are spread over multiple days.

What is the best approach to create such a calendar? Does a calendar control exists which takes some input arguments and can do the work for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description, the DayPilot Lite calendar control from DayPilot.org looks promising (it renders an outlook style day-at-a-glance hourly view): http://www.daypilot.org/

Sample output: http://blogs.teamb.com/files/2009/05/daypilot_1274.png

Here's a corresponding blog/tutorial (with a downloadable code) on how to use the control with ASP.NET MVC: http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/05/12/38297/

Comment: That was exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: DayPilot now has a special MVC version. Commercial: http://mvc.daypilot.org/ - and open-source: http://mvc.daypilot.org/lite/

Answer (score 0):

What sort of display are you after? Some searching shows a viable jQuery-based gantt here ([jquery.gantt](http://www.maro-z.com/examples/jquery.gantt/)). ILOG do a range of outlook-style calendar and gantt (task-based) / schedule (resource-based) controls for both winform and web, but they aren't free, and the web bits are currently non-MVC.

So; what sort of display are you after?

Comment: I'm looking for a day-to-day view where each day is split in two: a AM and PM part. Though the jquery gantt is coming close to what I'm looking for, it doesn't support my day-to-day scenario.